# Correct status code to send for an HTTP POST request where the given ID does not match an object in the database

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Lets say I have an endpoint in my API with the following URL:

```
www.example.com/api/create-order-for-restaurant/
```

Now, in my POST request, I send the following data:

```
{
    "restaurant_id": 43,
    "order": {...}
}
```

Lets say a restaurant with the id 43 does not exist in my database. What should be the appropriate HTTP status code that should be sent back to the client?

Im confused if I should be sending back `404` or `500`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a client error because the client specified a restaurant_id that didn't exist.

The default code for any client error is [400](https://evertpot.com/http/400-bad-request), and it would be fitting here too.
There are slightly more specific client error codes that might work well for this case, but it's not terribly important *unless* there is something a client can do with this information.

- [422](https://evertpot.com/http/422-unprocessable-entity) - could be considered correct. The JSON is parsable, it just contains invalid information.
- [409](https://evertpot.com/http/409-confict) - could be considered correct, if the client can create the restaurant with that specific id first. I assume that the server controls id's, so for that reason it's probably not right here.

So 400, 422 is fine. 500 is not. 500 implies that there's a server-side problem, but as far as I can tell you are describing a situation where the client used an incorrect restaurant_id.